# Create list of sublists

Tags: python, list, sublist

I have a list of 50,000 integers:

I want to create a list of sublists from this large list.

The sublist is created by finding within the list the position that has a difference with the first value of the list of 1,000,000.

Below is my code:

```
sub_pos_list = []
for i in range(0, len(pos_list)):    
    difference = pos_list[i] - pos_list[0]    
    if difference <= 1000000:
        sub_pos_list.append(pos_list[0:i])
```

However, this only grabs the first 1,000,000 difference. I want to then delete this region from the list and start over again.

I want to create multiple sublists of 1,000,000 difference and then make a list of these sublists.

Any suggestions how to do this?

Comment: The first line is: "I have a list of 50,000 integer values:"

Comment: Rodrigo, you can edit your question to fix the typo.

Comment: It's not clear what your input and desired output are. Can you give us an example with, say, 10 values instead of 50000, and what you want it to do?

Comment: And when should you stop?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `=>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly what You want to achieve, this is the solution:

```
sub_pos_list = []

last_found_pos = 0
for i in xrange(last_found_pos, len(pos_list)):
  difference = pos_list[i] - pos_list[last_found_pos]
  if difference >= 1000000:
    sub_pos_list.append(pos_list[last_found_pos:i + 1])
    last_found_pos = i
```

from:
 `pos_list = [0, 5, 1000000, 1000005, 2000005]`
it will give You:
`sub_pos_list == [ [0, 5, 1000000], [1000000, 1000005, 2000005] ]`

Comment: Hi Dzarafata, This is exactly what I wanted to achieve. Thank you for your help!